# How to automatically back up and version BigQuery code such as stored procs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

What are some of the options to back up BigQuery DDLs - particularly views, stored procedure and function code?

We have a significant amount of code in BigQuery and we want to automatically back this up and preferably version it as well. Wondering how others are doing this.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think if may be possible to use ordinary git and relevant CICD workflows to maintain all such things under version control? Thus (at least) the production environment gets all such things from git only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to keep and track our BigQuery structure and code, we're using Terraform to manage every resources in big query.
More specifically to your question, We use [google_bigquery_routine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_routine) resource to make sure the changes are reviewed by other team members and every other benefit you get from working with VCS.

Another important part of our TerraForm code is the fact we version our BigQuery module (via github releases/tags) that includes the Tables structure and Routines, version it and use it across multiple environments.

Looks something like:

main.tf

```
module "bigquery" {
  source = "github.com/sample-org/terraform-modules.git?ref=0.0.2/bigquery"

  project_id       = var.project_id


  ...
  ... other vars for the module
  ... 
}
```

terraform-modules/bigquery/main.tf

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "test" {
    dataset_id = "dataset_id"
    project_id = var.project_name
}

resource "google_bigquery_routine" "sproc" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.test.dataset_id
  routine_id     = "routine_id"
  routine_type = "PROCEDURE"
  language = "SQL"
  definition_body = "CREATE FUNCTION Add(x FLOAT64, y FLOAT64) RETURNS FLOAT64 AS (x + y);"
}
```

This helps us upgrading our infrastructure across all environments without additional code changes

Answer (score 1):

We finally ended up backing up DDLs and routines using INFORMATION_SCHEMA. A scheduled job extracts the relevant metadata and then uploads the content into GCS.

Example SQLs:

```
select * from <schema>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;
select * from <schema>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;
select *, DDL from <schema>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

You have to explicitly specify DDL in the column list for the table DDLs to show up.

Please check the documentation as these things evolve rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

I write a table/views and a routines (stored procedures and functions) definition file nightly to Cloud Storage using Cloud Run.  See [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/gcloud) about setting it up.  Cloud Run has an HTTP endpoint that is scheduled with Cloud Scheduler.  It essentially runs this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail

GCLOUD_REPORT_BUCKET="myproject-code/backups"

objects_report="gs://${GCLOUD_REPORT_BUCKET}/objects-backup-report-$(date +%s).txt"
routines_report="gs://${GCLOUD_REPORT_BUCKET}/routines-backup-report-$(date +%s).txt"
project_id="myproject-dw"
table_defs=()
routine_defs=()

# get list of datasets and table definitions
datasets=$(bq ls --max_results=1000 | grep -v -e "fivetran*" | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)

for dataset in $datasets
do
  echo ${project_id}:${dataset} 

  # write tables and views to file
  tables=$(bq ls --max_results 1000 ${project_id}:${dataset} | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)
  for table in $tables
  do
    echo ${project_id}:${dataset}.${table}
    table_defs+="$(bq show --format=prettyjson ${project_id}:${dataset}.${table})"
  done

  # write routines (stored procs and functions) to file
  routines=$(bq ls --max_results 1000 --routines=true ${project_id}:${dataset} | awk '{print $1}' | tail +3)
  for routine in $routines
  do
    echo ${project_id}:${dataset}.${routine}
    routine_defs+="$(bq show --format=prettyjson --routine=true ${project_id}:${dataset}.${routine})"
  done

done

echo $table_defs | jq '.' | gsutil -q cp -J - "${objects_report}"
echo $routine_defs | jq '.' | gsutil -q cp -J - "${routines_report}"

# /dev/stderr is sent to Cloud Logging.
echo "objects-backup-report: wrote to ${objects_report}" >&2
echo "Wrote objects report to ${objects_report}"
echo "routines-backup-report: wrote to ${routines_report}" >&2
echo "Wrote routines report to ${routines_report}"
```

The output is essentially the same as writing a `bq ls` and `bq show` commands for all datasets with the results piped to a text file with a date.  I may add this to git, but the file includes a timestamp so you know the state of BigQuery by reviewing the file for a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I had this issue today and created a PowerShell script that exports the DDLs using Google CLI.

It is not perfect (and I don't use PS a lot), but it works for me, and someone else can use it as a starting point.

The program creates a filer per "object" (table, view, procedure, etc), so you can add those files to source control.

Update your Project ID, Dataset and Output folder.

As I mentioned, you need Google CLI installed and authenticated!

```
# Set your Project and Dataset IDs
$projectId = "<YOUR PROJECT ID>"
$dataset = "<YOUR DATASET NAME>"
$output = "${PSScriptRoot}\<YOUR SUB-FOLDER>"

# Delete output files
Get-ChildItem -Path $output -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }

# Get the list of all tables in the dataset
$tables = bq ls --format=prettyjson --project_id $projectId $dataset | ConvertFrom-Json

# Process each table
foreach ($table in $tables) {
    # Get the table ID
    $tableName = $table.tableReference.tableId
    $type = $table.type

    # Get the DDL of the table
    $query = "select ddl from ${projectId}.${dataset}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name='${tableName}';"
    $ddl = bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false $query | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Define the file name for saving the DDL
    $fileName = "${type}_${tableName}.sql"
    $fileName

    # Save the DDL to a file
    $contents = $ddl.ddl
    $contents | Out-File -FilePath "${output}\${fileName}"
}


# Get the list of all routines (Stored Procedures and Functions) in the dataset
$routines = bq ls --format=prettyjson --routines --project_id $projectId $dataset | ConvertFrom-Json

# Process each routine
foreach ($routine in $routines) {
    # Get routine type (PROCEDURE or FUNCTION)
    $type = $routine.routineType

    # Get the routine ID
    $routineId = $routine.routineReference.routineId

    # Get the DDL of the routine
    $query = "select ddl from ${projectId}.${dataset}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where routine_name='${routineId}';"
    $ddl = bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false $query | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Define the file name for saving the DDL
    $fileName = "${type}_${routineId}.sql"
    $fileName

    # Save the DDL to a file
    $contents = $ddl.ddl
    $contents | Out-File -FilePath "${output}\${fileName}"
}
```

Hope it helps.